# Color of the input text change when you chose from the suggestion drop down

Tags: html, css, input

So, I'm having a normal form with  input fields and I want it to be with a different look on mobile and desktop.
When it is on **mobile** it looks like this:

```
 color: #FF6B00;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: underline #FF6B00;
```

and on **desktop** to be like this

```
 color: #000;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-decoration: none;
```

so on mobile  should be  orange and when you write it's orange but when the suggestion drop down opens up ,
and i chose from it, the color is changed to black.

Comment: media queries ?

Comment: I have a media queries  but and when you write its okey it takes the orange color.But when  I use suggestion from the  drop down it makes it black again.

Comment: Then you are propably using the wrong selectors

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Which suggestion dropdown are you using? Your suggestion plugin might be changing the input by adding a class or something.

Comment: Default chrome dropdown that gives you emails that you have write before

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` on dropdown css;

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand  what you mean

Comment: color: #000!important;